# Prove that there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that $L(h) = \alpha h$

Tags: real-analysis

Given a linear function $L : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I have to prove that there exists a real number $\alpha$ such that

$$
L(h) = \alpha h \ \ \ \text{for all} \ \ \ h \in \mathbb{R}
$$
but I don't have an idea where to start. Can you guide me in the right direction? To me this only makes sense if $\alpha = 0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linear implies that $L(\lambda x)=\lambda L(x)$ for all $\lambda, x\in \mathbb R$.  Thus $L(h)=hL(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Does this imply that $\alpha = L(1)$?

Comment: Yes, it does.  $\quad$